# Minimum number of triangles with given diameter

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, and diameter $d$ of $G$, can we compute the minimum number of triangles that must exist in $G$? In other words, can we give a lower bound on the number of triangles in terms of $d, n, m$ where $n = |V|$ and $m= |E|$?

Clearly, the problem is trivial when $d=1$, because, $G$ is then a complete graph. Can we compute the minimum number of triangles when say $d=2$?

Answer (score 1):

As the following example shows, there does not need to be any triangle in $G$ if $\text{diam}(G) = 2$:

[image]

If $n$ is even, the bipartite graph $K_{n/2,n/2}$ has diameter $2$, no triangles, and the maximum number of $n^2/4$ edges. A graph with more than $n^2/4$ edges has at least one triangle by [Turán's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem).